# Convert Html to PDF using wkhtmltopdf

Tags: pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I'm using wkhtmltopdf to convert pages to pdf but when I want to convert a secured page by user name and password but the site redirects the url to another page which requests the username and password although the user is already logged in.

The method which convert uses a process`var p = new System.Diagnostics.Process()
                {
                    StartInfo =
                    {
                        FileName = pdfHtmlToPdfExePath,
                        Arguments = ((options == null) ? "" : String.Join(" ", options)) + " " + urlsSeparatedBySpaces + " " + outputFilename,
                        UseShellExecute = false, // needs to be false in order to redirect output
                        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                        RedirectStandardError = true,
                        RedirectStandardInput = false, // redirect all 3, as it should be all 3 or none
                        WorkingDirectory = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(outputFolder)
                    }
                };`

Anyone has any idea how to get out of this problem?

Comment: do you have working version now?

Comment: @Dhara I got this working but I left the project years ago, I'm sorry I don't have the solution.

Comment: oh! not an issue :) @Fakhry

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to the documentation (http://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt) you should be able to pass cookies as arguments.

Try with code like the below before starting the external process, then the cookies you as user are sending to the server should be included with the request.

```
foreach(var cookie in System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies)
{
    options += string.Format(" --cookie {0} {1}", cookie.Name, cookie.Value)
}
```